# Ideas to recreate this using latex

Tags: positioning, boxes

I'd like to create a Latex template similar to the one on the picture. Basically it's a set of boxes with different fields plus the big box on the bottom with a graphic. 
I've been analysing several possibilities, but I'm unsure as to the simplest approach would be.

I'm thinking of using minipages and frameboxes, but I'm unsure as to whether there is another (simpler) approach...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance:

Pedro

[image]

Comment: Should the boxes be fillable with text, as in a form?

Comment: `tcbraster` and a bunch of tcolorboxes, but really, it's a lot of work with that...

Comment: In the past I have used the `picture` environment for this sort of thing.

Comment: I remember reading a TUG article about those kind of medical documents issued some years age. It would be worth looking for it.

Comment: @ samcarter: yes. The boxes will be filled with text from another document...

Comment: I would do the whole thing with TikZ, using empty rectangle nodes and placing the text and shaded spaces relative to the anchor points.

Answer (score 4):

Following the advice of @John Kormylo, I've started looking at TikZ. In the meanwhile, I've found an utility to convert from SVG to TikZ (https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz), which saved me a lot of time, since I already had an SVG template.

I believe now it's just a matter of fine tuning. 
While this is still WIP, I've managed to create an usable template with all the fields I need using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\sffamily\tiny}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\myfont}}}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{ceaeaea}{RGB}{234,234,234}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-3.40000, xscale=3.40000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[draw=black,miter limit=10.00,nonzero rule,line width=0.207pt,rounded
corners=0.0000cm] (31.2797,43.0447) rectangle (178.7203,252.4853);
\path[fill=black] (0.0000,0.0000) node[above right] (flowRoot4524) {};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(294.3900,96.4443) node[above right] (text4770-2) {};
\path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (295.5916,96.4856) node[above right]
(text1077) {};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(143.3438,50.8601) node[above right] (text4733) {Data};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (141.6885,46.9393) --
(178.7048,46.9393) -- (178.7048,71.5803) -- (141.6885,71.5803) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
rule,line width=0.400pt] (141.8046,59.1590) -- (178.7048,59.1590);
\path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
rule,line width=0.400pt] (165.3336,59.1590) -- (165.3336,71.5803);
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(143.4002,62.6282) node[above right] (text4758) {P (m)};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(166.6337,62.2359) node[above right] (text4762) {TM (min)};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.1990,46.9393) --
(64.9426,46.9393) -- (64.9426,54.9639) -- (46.1990,54.9639) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (66.0925,46.9393) --
(140.4420,46.9393) -- (140.4420,54.9639) -- (66.0925,54.9639) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(67.8957,50.1904) node[above right] (text4770) {Local};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.8226,50.5990) node[above right] (text4774) {Nº};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.2398,112.2409) --
(178.7500,112.2409) -- (178.7500,162.1446) -- (46.2398,162.1446) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.2224,56.1200) --
(140.4864,56.1200) -- (140.4864,65.8242) -- (46.2224,65.8242) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (141.6497,88.2279) --
(178.7500,88.2279) -- (178.7500,111.1826) -- (141.6497,111.1826) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(143.4002,92.2893) node[above right] (text4770-1) {Rubrica(s)};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.6782,59.4158) node[above right] (text4770-9) {Companheiro(s)};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.2243,67.2150) --
(81.6619,67.2150) -- (81.6619,77.8195) -- (46.2243,77.8195) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (83.1621,67.1952) --
(140.4809,67.1952) -- (140.4809,77.9541) -- (83.1621,77.9541) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.5653,71.0898) node[above right] (text4770-5) {Hora de entrada};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.5653,116.3007) node[above right] (text4770-0) {Notas};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.2398,163.5650) --
(178.7500,163.5650) -- (178.7500,250.0813) -- (46.0100,250.0813) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(84.6744,70.9296) node[above right] (text4770-0-8) {Tipo};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.2062,79.0382) --
(81.6900,79.0382) -- (81.6900,96.5244) -- (46.2062,96.5244) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.2763,81.9121) node[above right] (text4770-0-8-6) {Condições};
\path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (83.0913,79.1084) --
(140.4102,79.1084) -- (140.4102,102.4919) -- (83.0913,102.4919) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(83.9829,82.4187) node[above right] (text4770-1-4) {Equipamento};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(83.9731,85.9818) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4) {Fato};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(47.9841,101.0407) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-9) {Gás/Gases usado(s)};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(84.6947,96.4994) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4-8) {Lastro (kg)};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.0161,82.5229) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4-85) {Garrafa(s)};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(83.8753,107.2107) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4-2) {Classificação};
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.237pt] (52.0351,48.3821) --
(63.9225,48.3821) -- (63.9225,53.4974) -- (52.0351,53.4974) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (75.7594,48.0878) --
(138.9287,48.0878) -- (138.9287,53.7918) -- (75.7594,53.7918) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (151.9595,48.0878) --
(177.3603,48.0878) -- (177.3603,57.9656) -- (151.9595,57.9656) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (151.9595,60.7878) --
(163.2484,60.7878) -- (163.2484,70.6656) -- (151.9595,70.6656) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (167.4817,63.6100) --
(177.3603,63.6100) -- (177.3603,70.6656) -- (167.4817,70.6656) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (47.6048,60.2613) --
(138.9287,60.2613) -- (138.9287,64.8152) -- (47.6048,64.8152) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (47.6048,72.3524) --
(79.9928,72.3524) -- (79.9928,76.5857) -- (47.6048,76.5857) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (91.2817,69.0384) --
(138.9287,69.0384) -- (138.9287,76.7006) -- (91.2817,76.7006) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (47.6048,89.4257) --
(56.7819,89.4257) -- (56.7819,95.7385) -- (47.6048,95.7385) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (57.8906,89.4257) --
(66.6754,89.4257) -- (66.6754,95.7385) -- (57.8906,95.7385) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (84.2261,86.8029) --
(111.0589,86.8029) -- (111.0589,93.2491) -- (84.2261,93.2491) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm]
(96.0106,94.9564) rectangle (110.8965,100.6008);
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (112.4484,83.4252) --
(138.9287,83.4252) -- (138.9287,100.6068) -- (112.4484,100.6068) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (47.6048,117.2322) --
(177.3603,117.2322) -- (177.3603,160.9767) -- (47.6048,160.9767) -- cycle;
 \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (46.1464,97.8147) --
(81.6854,97.8147) -- (81.6854,111.1044) -- (46.1464,111.1044) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (47.6048,102.0179) --
(79.5378,102.0179) -- (79.5378,110.2253) -- (47.6048,110.2253) -- cycle;
 \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (83.0350,103.6984) --
(140.4338,103.6984) -- (140.4338,111.1378) -- (83.0350,111.1378) -- cycle;
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (100.8473,104.9735) --
(138.9287,104.9735) -- (138.9287,109.7629) -- (100.8473,109.7629) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(53.0323,51.8397) node[above right] (text4770-3) {\ssrfnumber};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(52.2853,63.9487) node[above right] (text4770-53) {\ssrfbuddy};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(80.0001,51.5671) node[above right] (text4770-6) {\ssrfplace};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(58.6353,75.3258) node[above right] (text4770-12) {Local};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(98.3228,74.0029) node[above right] (text4770-09) {\ssrftype};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(48.3827,92.2260) node[above right] (text4770-60) {\ssrfwatertemp};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(58.5408,92.2260) node[above right] (text4770-61) {\ssrfairtemp};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(89.0624,89.8779) node[below right, text width=2cm] (text4770-7) {\ssrfsuit};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(96.7068,98.3194) node[above right] (text4770-02) {\ssrfweightaamt};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(48.0519,104.4300) node[above right] (text4770-59) {\ssrfcylagasname};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.8749,86.1737) node[above right] (text4770-36)
{\ssrfcyladescription};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(102.4768,108.0755) node[above right] (text4770-19) {\ssrfrating};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(48.0519,121.6278) node[above right, text width=12cm] (text4770-361) {\ssrfcomment};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(156.5311,54.1591) node[above right] (text4770-63) {\ssrfdate};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.612pt]
(152.6864,64.0571) node[above right] (text4770-615){\ssrfmaximumdepth};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(168.4374,67.3883) node[above right] (text4770-76) {\ssrftime};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(143.4002,74.6774) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4-0) {Pmédia (m)};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(163.1792,74.8197) node[above right] (text4770-1-4-4-1) {SAC (l/min)};
 \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.400pt] (141.6885,71.5803) --
(178.7048,71.5803) -- (178.7048,87.3338) -- (141.6885,87.3338) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (143.2308,76.1474) --
(157.0478,76.1474) -- (157.0478,85.9424) -- (143.2308,85.9424) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (162.4118,76.1474) --
(177.3603,76.1474) -- (177.3603,85.9424) -- (162.4118,85.9424) -- cycle;
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(143.7744,81.7278) node[above right] (text4770-93) {\ssrfmeandepth};
\path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (57.9753,174.6333) node[inner sep=0pt]
(plot) at (111,207) {\ssrfplot};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.8749,89.0695) node[above right] (text4770-36-4)
{\ssrfcylbdescription};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(48.2545,107.7221) node[above right] (text4770-59-3)
{\ssrfcylbgasname};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.8749,91.9653) node[above right] (text4770-36-4-7)
{\ssrfcylcdescription};
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.8749,94.8611) node[above right] (text4770-36-4-6)
{\ssrfcylddescription};
 \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (370.9979,63.4127) node[above right]
(text1153) {\ssrfmeandepth};
 \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (382.9041,71.3502) node[above right]
(text1157) {\ssrfviz};
 \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (378.9354,77.9648) node[above right]
(text1161) {\ssrfcomputer};
 \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (380.2583,88.5481) node[above right]
(text1165) {\ssrfgasuse};
 \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (380.2583,96.4856) node[above right]
(text1169) {\ssrfsac};
 \begin{scope}[shift={(1.67314,1.98097)}]
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
  (47.8009,86.8125) node[above right] (text4770-0-8-7) {Água};
 \end{scope}
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(60.9135,88.8432) node[above right] (text4770-0-8-7-8) {Ar};
\begin{scope}[shift={(-3.13355,0.88681)}]
 \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
  (50.4592,84.4211) node[above right] (text4770-0-8-7-9) {Temperatura (   )};
 \begin{scope}[cm={{0.67131,0.0,0.0,0.67131,(40.73125,27.94586)}}]
  \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (34.6448,84.3166) node[above right]
    (text2902-7) {C};
  \path[fill=black,line width=0.212pt] (33.8568,82.9860) node[above right]
    (text2924-9) {o};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(68.5767,85.5143) node[above right] (text4770-0-8-7-9-0) {Visibilidade};
\path[fill=ceaeaea,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.240pt] (69.9744,89.4257) --
(78.7592,89.4257) -- (78.7592,95.7385) -- (69.9744,95.7385) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(70.8431,92.3657) node[above right] (text4770-61-0) {\ssrfviz};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(165.9193,81.7164) node[above right] (text4770-93-3) {\ssrfsac};
\path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
(112.8749,97.7568) node[above right] (text4770-36-4-6-5)
{\ssrfcyledescription};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you all for the hints.

Comment: The problem is that the convert is not smart, produces a lot of complicated coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best I manage to do with `tcolorbox`'s `poster`library. The grey box was not included and some tricks with tables.

I am not an expert with `tcolorbox` so any suggestions/corrections are welcome.

Other questions you might want to have a look: [this boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451457/create-page-layout-with-beautiful-boxes-tcolorbox), [this form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394352/tcolorbox-layer-and-height-in-raster) and [this other form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368551/how-do-i-create-the-following-box-with-texts-in-latex).

[image: poster form]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many,poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {,spacing=1.5mm,columns=8,rows=25} , %showframe},
boxes  = {sharp corners,colback=white,left=0mm,right=0mm},
]
\posterbox{name=Numero,column=1,span=1.5,row=1,}{ \#}
\posterbox{name=Local,column=2,span=4.5,row=1,,xshift=11.9mm}{ Local}
\posterbox{name=Data,column=7,span=2,row=1,rowspan=1.5}{ Data}
%
\begin{posterboxenv}[sidebyside,segmentation style={solid}]{name=PTM,column=7,span=2,below=Data,rowspan=1.72,yshift=2.5mm,} 
P(m)
\tcblower
TM(min)
\end{posterboxenv}
\posterbox{name=Rubrica,column=7,span=2,row=4,rowspan=3,}{ Rubrica(s)}
\begin{posterboxenv}[sidebyside,segmentation hidden]{name=OTU,column=7,span=2,below=Rubrica,rowspan=3,}
OTU's
\tcblower
CNS
\end{posterboxenv}
%
%
%
\posterbox{name=Companheiro,column=1,span=6,row=2}{ Companheiro(s)}
%
\posterbox{name=Hora,column=1,span=2,row=3,rowspan=2}{ Hora de entrada}
\posterbox{name=Tipo,column=3,span=4,row=3,rowspan=2}{ Tipo}
%
\begin{posterboxenv}[sidebyside,segmentation hidden,title=Condições,titlerule=0mm,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black]{name=Condicoes,column=1,span=2,row=5,rowspan=3}
Temp.\ água
\tcblower
Temp.\ ar
\end{posterboxenv}
%
\begin{posterboxenv}[sidebyside,segmentation hidden,title=Equipamento,titlerule=0mm,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black]{name=Equipamento,column=3,span=4,row=5,rowspan=4}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Fato \\ 
\\
\\
\\
Lastro (kg) \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\tcblower
\begin{tabular}{l}
Garrata(s) \\ 
\\
\\
\\
 \\ 
 \end{tabular}
\end{posterboxenv}
%
\posterbox{name=Gas,column=1,span=2,row=8,rowspan=2}{ Gás/Gases usado(s)}
\posterbox{name=Classificacao,column=3,span=4,row=9,rowspan=1}{ Classificação}
%
\posterbox{name=Notas,column=1,span=8,row=10,rowspan=6}{ Notas}
\posterbox{name=Perfil,column=1,span=8,row=16,rowspan=10}{ Perfil

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\tcbtextwidth,height=9cm]{example-image}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```